# Query is taking much time when value of rownum is exceeding from 49000 to more

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pagination

I am using Oracle 11g. I have a table that have 45 millions of rows.

```
Table Schema: 
TableName: INFO
  (
    ID                NUMBER NOT NULL ,   (Primary Key)
    USER_NAME         VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), (has less unique values)
    DATED             DATE,               (has less unique values)   
    URI               VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE),(Unique Key)
    APPLICATION_TYPE  VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), (has less unique values) 
    INFORMATION       CLOB
  )
```

and also have one index that created on:

```
create index check_index on INFO(dated desc, upper(uri), upper(user_name) asc);
```

Now the query is:

```
   SELECT  rnum,id,dated,URI,user_name,information,application_type  FROM            
        ( SELECT rownum rnum,id,dated,URI,user_name,information,application_type FROM
      (select info.id,info.dated,info.URI,info.user_name,info.information,info.application_type  from INFO
          where  LOWER(info.uri) like 'model://%' and  
          info.dated >= to_date('01-01-2014 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY hh24:mi:ss') and info.dated <= to_date('31-12-2014 23:59:59', 'DD-MM-YYYY hh24:mi:ss')  
          and info.user_name = 'whl'  order by dated desc, upper(uri), upper(user_name) asc 
) WHERE  rownum <= 49000
    )WHERE rnum >= 48900 ;
```

Explain Plan for this is:

```
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
Plan hash value: 3477643426                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                               
| Id  | Operation                      | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |                                                                                                                                                                                                               
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                               
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT               |             | 49000 |    27M|     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                               
|*  1 |  VIEW                          |             | 49000 |    27M|     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                               
|*  2 |   COUNT STOPKEY                |             |       |       |            |          |                                                                                                                                                                                                               
|   3 |    VIEW                        |             | 49000 |    26M|     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                               
|*  4 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| AUDIT_INFO  |  1025K|   301M|     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                               
|*  5 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN          | CHECK_INDEX |     1 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                               
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                               

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
---------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

   1 - filter("RNUM">=48900)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
   2 - filter(ROWNUM<=49000)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
   4 - filter("INFO"."USER_NAME"='whl' AND LOWER("INFO"."URI") LIKE 'model://%')                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
   5 - access(SYS_OP_DESCEND("DATED")>=HEXTORAW('878DF3E0E7C3C3FF')  AND                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
              SYS_OP_DESCEND("DATED")<=HEXTORAW('878DFEF8FEF8FEFAFF') )                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
       filter(SYS_OP_UNDESCEND(SYS_OP_DESCEND("DATED"))>=TO_DATE(' 2014-01-01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
              00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND SYS_OP_UNDESCEND(SYS_OP_DESCEND("DATED"))<=TO                                                                                                                                                                                                         
              _DATE(' 2014-12-31 23:59:59', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
```

Auto trace info:

```
db block gets:   12
consistent gets: 2
physical reads:  0
redo size:       808
bytes sent via sql *net to client:580   




  And Explain Plan after increasing the value of rownum from 49000 to 60,000 and rnum from 48900 to 59900 is:
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
Plan hash value: 3477643426                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                               
| Id  | Operation                      | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |                                                                                                                                                                                                               
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                               
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT               |             | 60000 |    33M|     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                               
|*  1 |  VIEW                          |             | 60000 |    33M|     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                               
|*  2 |   COUNT STOPKEY                |             |       |       |            |          |                                                                                                                                                                                                               
|   3 |    VIEW                        |             | 60000 |    32M|     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                               
|*  4 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| AUDIT_INFO  |  1025K|   301M|     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                               
|*  5 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN          | CHECK_INDEX |     1 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                               
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                               

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
---------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

   1 - filter("RNUM">=59900)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
   2 - filter(ROWNUM<=60000)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
   4 - filter("INFO"."USER_NAME"='whl' AND LOWER("INFO"."URI") LIKE 'model://%')                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
   5 - access(SYS_OP_DESCEND("DATED")>=HEXTORAW('878DF3E0E7C3C3FF')  AND                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
              SYS_OP_DESCEND("DATED")<=HEXTORAW('878DFEF8FEF8FEFAFF') )                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
       filter(SYS_OP_UNDESCEND(SYS_OP_DESCEND("DATED"))>=TO_DATE(' 2014-01-01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
              00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND SYS_OP_UNDESCEND(SYS_OP_DESCEND("DATED"))<=TO                                                                                                                                                                                                         
              _DATE(' 2014-12-31 23:59:59', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))                                                                                                                                                                         auto trace info:
db block gets:   6
consistent gets: 1
physical reads:  0
redo size:       860
bytes sent via sql *net to client: 582
```

if i execute this query it returns 100 rows in 0.865 second.
Now the problem is if i increase the value of rownum from 49000 to 51000 or more and also the value of rnum corresponding to rownum then it takes much time, approximate 64sec or more.

and if i remove both rownum and rnum from query then all query gets executed in 0.894 second

So i wanted to know that what is the main problem or anything that is taking the time and how can i resolve this by anyway to take time in milliseconds or approx 1~2 seconds only.
thanks

Comment: Show us explain plan for both queries. The answer will be there...

Comment: Your URI is unique and you don't use it in your select. Why do you need LOWER and UPPER on this field?

Comment: @Robert post has been edited. i have added both explain plan. can you please look in to this. thanks for quick reply

Comment: @Multisync URI column is also used in select. can you please check it again. lower and upper is the demand of situation so i can not remove it from here.

Comment: Well the answer is not there ;-) Plan looks the same. Try set autotrace on and compare output. Since we don't have any knowledge of your hardware, database settings etc. it will be difficult for us to help you.

Comment: @Robert i have updated the auto trace info differences between these two plans in this post and tell me exactly what you need to know about hardware and database configuration. i will provide all information required.

Comment: why dont use paralell? at least 8 or 10

Comment: @Thomas sorry! i didn't get your means.

Comment: use the parallel hint e.g.: select /*+parallel(8)*/ rnum,id,dated...

Comment: i think this will help a little :)

Comment: @Thomas yeah it's helping only a little bit but it's not what i want exactly, anyway thanks